# Appkit examples on OSX 10.6

Tags: macos, appkit

I'm trying to re-invent Preview.app. I've been told that some examples in /Developers/Examples/AppKit will help me. However, on my 10.6 system, I don't have such a folder.

Did the examples get moved? Is my installation somehow incomplete? will the examples I copy from a 10.5 system work?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting ReadMe.rtf on /Developer/Examples:

> The Xcode projects that were formerly installed locally in the /Developer/Examples/ folder are now in the ADC Reference Library. The ADC Reference Library now provides access to all documentation and sample code.
>
> Using Xcode, find sample code in the Documentation window. Search for samples by title, search for symbols that you're interested in, or use the reference library navigation to find samples by topic or framework. Documents in the reference library are organized by resource type, which allows you to choose the type of document most relevant to your needs, including sample code. You can view all sample code, navigate to a particular topic and see relevant sample code for that topic, or navigate to a framework that you're interested in and see sample code that specifically focuses on that framework.
>
> Find sample code using your web browser by going to the Mac Dev Center, linked from http://developer.apple.com.
>
> From there, go to the reference library.

Hope that helped!